# Wxpython panel will automatically leave a text image when you load it

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.data = ['111111','2222','333','4','555']
        self.testcombo =  wx.ComboBox(self.mainPanel,-1, choices=self.data, pos=(0,0))
#        self.testcombo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.comboSave)
        self.dataLabel = wx.StaticText(self.mainPanel,-1,("Nothing Saved Yet"),pos=(100,50))
        self.dataLabel2 = wx.StaticText(self.mainPanel,-1, pos=(100,100))
        self.testbut = wx.Button(self.mainPanel, wx.ID_SAVE, pos=(0,180))
        self.testbut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.dataSave, id=wx.ID_SAVE )

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test1.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(TEST CHAR(5))')

        self.autorefresh()

#    def comboSave(self, e):
#        self.testcomboSave = self.testcombo.GetValue()

    def dataSave(self, e):
        self.testcomboSave = self.testcombo.GetValue()
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TEST(TEST) VALUES(?)', (self.testcomboSave, ))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.dataLabel.SetLabel(self.testcomboSave)

    def comboLoad(self):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM TEST')
        for dbLoad in self.cursor.fetchall():pass
        self.dbLoad = dbLoad[0]
        self.dataLabel2.SetLabel(self.dbLoad)

    def autorefresh(self):
        self.comboLoad()
        wx.CallLater(1000, self.autorefresh)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I load the contents of the combo box into sqilte3 and then automatically load it into the panel, there is an afterimage in the text. I do not know why. Is this a bug?

ex) 111111 -> 2222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, you are over-laying one piece of text with another.
Banging in a new `wx.StaticText` for every iteration in function `comboLoad` is not the way to go about it. Create the statictext initially and then update it's value as you go.
You also have redundant code, your `autorefresh` function is loading the contents of the database once a second for no obvious reason, especially as the database has no declared key, which means that you can input the same values over and over again and never get an error.
I have commented out the redundant code, so that you can see, what is and what is not required.
I trust that this more accurately meets your needs than my previous post.

```
import wx
import sqlite3

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.data = ['111111','2222','333','4','555']
        self.testcombo =  wx.ComboBox(self.mainPanel,-1, choices=self.data, pos=(0,0))
#        self.testcombo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.comboSave)
        self.dataLabel = wx.StaticText(self.mainPanel,-1,("Nothing Saved Yet"),pos=(100,50))
        self.testbut = wx.Button(self.mainPanel, wx.ID_SAVE, pos=(0,180))
        self.testbut.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.dataSave, id=wx.ID_SAVE )

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test1.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(TEST CHAR(5))')

#        self.autorefresh()

#    def comboSave(self, e):
#        self.testcomboSave = self.testcombo.GetValue()

    def dataSave(self, e):
        self.testcomboSave = self.testcombo.GetValue()
        self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO TEST(TEST) VALUES(?)', (self.testcomboSave, ))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.dataLabel.SetLabel("Item Saved to database: "+self.testcomboSave)

#    def comboLoad(self):
#        self.cursor.execute('SELECT *FROM TEST')
#        for dbLoad in self.cursor.fetchall():pass
#        wx.StaticText(self.mainPanel,label=dbLoad[0],pos=(100,100)
#
#    def autorefresh(self):
#        self.comboLoad()
#        wx.CallLater(1000,self.autorefresh)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What I want is not to list the database data, but I want to change the contents of the combo box whenever I change it. I would like to ask you how to solve this.

Ex1) combo 11111 choice -> panel text 11111
Ex2) combo 4 choice -> panel text 41111 (11111 <- afterimage??? bug??)

Comment: I have altered the code to provide, what I now think, you are asking for.

Comment: I am modifying the code Applied the "Self.dataLabel2.SetLabel (self.dbLoad)" part. Thank you. It was a really good teaching. I learned a lot.